# Unicode mapping...ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, web, c#-2.0, globalization

Greetings,

I have been developing site that uses globalization in asp.net(well,actually it's not globalization) :)

What I want to do is i want to show my website in multiple languages(fixed-: English,Gurmuki and Shahmukhi (Indic languages)).

To show these markup on screen i have done mapping..for example

Char  Unicode Shahmukhi-Char   Unicode         garmukhi-char  Unicode
A     65        character       unicode         Character of   unicode of
                  of Shahmukhi   of shahmukhi    garmukhi        garmukhi

I have created a demo with jQuery and do mapping as above for each character replacement..
Is there another better way to do so in ASP.net c#.
Let me know if you find uncomfortable with the information i have provided.

Important thing, I don't want to use already made components such as google Translation or other third party.I am willing to develop on my own..just need the way to do so.

Thank you and best regards.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by mapping... Can you rephrase your example "Char Unicode Shahmukhi-Char Unicode garmukhi-char Unicode A 65 character unicode Character of unicode of of Shahmukhi of shahmukhi garmukhi garmukhi"? I can't make sense of this line.

Comment: A-Unicode is 65 and a has unicode of 97 -- English
ژ-Unicode is 0698 and م has unicode of 0645 -- Shahmukhi

Comment: A-Unicode - 65 and a has 97 -- English
ژ-Unicode- 0698 and م has 0645 -- Shahmukhi
ਓ-Unicode- 0A13 -- Gurumukhi
Now i have done mapping that when user presses A--i will find unicode of that..which is 65, then i have mappping as 65-->0698--->0A13  somif i want to show in shahmmukhi then i will use 0698 and if i want to show in garmukhi then i will use 0A13 as replacement to 65. so it shows conversion. Don't know wheather it's right way or not....This works fine. Now to show aspirate contstants which uses multiple unicodes for ex 06BE+ 0628 to show بھ  to show 0A13 i'm using &x0A13;

Comment: I don't know anything about Indic languages but are saying that you are performing transliteration? Transliteration is something done between two written languages (e.g. Engish and Greek, and English and Arabic) by just mapping characters from one alphabet to another. It's not linguistically correct but is done informally for convenience. Is this what you are doing?

Comment: Yes, i'm doing so. I think visual would be right but the meaning won't get matched in such case..If i am not wrong....

Comment: I don't think I get it. Can you provide a screen shot or something?